# Trying to remove a single record from the table, but it is removing the whole records from reacthooks page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In a `react-hooks` page I am trying to remove a single record from the table, but now it is removing the whole records from UI. Could someone please help to identify the issue here ?

```
 const [currentRecord, setCurrentRecord] = useState([]);

  const removeRecord = (index) =>{
    const newList = currentRecord.filter((item) => index !== index);
    setCurrentRecord(newList);
  }
         <div className="purchasedbooks">
            <h2>Transaction record</h2>
            <table className="purchasetable result">
              <th>Item no</th>
              <th>Books</th>
              <th>Units</th>
              <th>Amount (AUD)</th>
              <th>Discount Amount (AUD)</th>
              <th>Final Amount (AUD)</th>
              {
                currentRecord.map(({ book, units, price, discount, finalamount }, index) => (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                    <td>{book}</td>
                    <td>{units}</td>
                    <td>{price}</td>
                    <td>{discount}</td>
                    <td>{finalamount}</td>
                    <span onClick={()=>removeRecord(index)} className="removeRecord">
                      -
                    </span>
                  </tr>
                ))
              }

            </table>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  const removeRecord = (index) =>{
    const newList = currentRecord.filter((item) => index !== index);
    setCurrentRecord(newList);
  }
```

to

```
  const removeRecord = (indexToRemove) =>{
    const newList = currentRecord.filter((item, index) => index !== indexToRemove);
    setCurrentRecord(newList);
  }
```

Comment: So the filter method will keep all of the records which are not equal to indexToRemove, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, only the `indexToRemove` index will be removed